# Regex in .htaccess combining two negative conditions

Tags: regex, .htaccess

could someone check this regex I wrote, it does what I wanted to achieve, but I'm not sure if it's the correct way to do it and if it's not slowing everything up

That's what it should do:

IF the URL Path is longer than the domain only
AND IF it doesn't contain the strings "/de" or "/en" at the beginning
THEN 301 it to the domain only

That's what I wrote:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?example\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!.*(/de|/en))
RewriteRule .* http://example.com/ [L,R=301]
```

... is there a better way to achieve that?

Thanks!!
Urs

Comment: `the URL Path is longer than the domain only`. What do you mean by that? Cause mod_rewrite can't check text-length.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that you did a "mindfart" and the second cond should read `%{REQUEST_URI}` otherwise it makes no sense as HTTP_HOST will never include a /

In runtime it makes very little difference, but it is easier to understand if written as

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/de|/en)
```

Comment: I've reflected again on what I want to do, it's even simpler than what I sketched above: If REQUEST_URI doesn't start with /de or /en, add /de in front of it. Can you help me do that? (and also maybe point me to a good mod_rewrite tutorial)?

Comment: Use what is called a negative lookahead assertion on the rule pattern, \(described [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)\)  E.g. `RewriteRule ^(?!de/)(?!en/).*  - [L]`. (no leading `/` on rule patterns in `.htaccess` files).  Use [this script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153262/tips-for-debugging-htaccess-rewrite-rules/9261963#9261963) to play with rule patterns.  As to tutorials, there's this thing called Google.  I learn't them before Google existed.  LoL.  Enjoy!!